# Discord.py returning users name without using the on-message function?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've recently started revamping my discord bots by not using the `on_message` function plus a long list of if statements, but now that I've started using `@bot.command(name="   ")` if I try and use message.author it doesn't have a message to check for an Author. How can I fix this?

```
@bot.command(name="start")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx):
        if not currentcreator == 0:
                await message.channel.send("Someone is already making a profile, 
                please wait")
                currentcreater = message.author
                dir = r'C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\DiscordMMO\User-Profiles'
                MessageAuthor = str(message.author)
                ProfileDIR = os.path.join(dir,MessageAuthor)
                doesExist = os.path.exists(ProfileDIR)
               if doesExist == False:
               embed=discord.Embed(title="Creating Profile", url="", description=MessageAuthor+", your profile is being create
```

Comment: Could you supply a snippet of the code you are using?

Comment: Edited it into the post

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but you have not defined the `message` variable? You can also use `ctx.author` to fetch the author. You can also directly use `ctx.send()` to respond. More info in the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ctx** is your command.
Image you have loads of methods inside of this for example.

ctx.author | The command author

ctx.channel.guild | The guild.

Have a look at the docs.

But what you're asking for is **ctx.author**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code, if you're lazy, I don't recommend copying tho.

```
@bot.command(name="start")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx):
        if currentcreator != 0:
                await ctx.send("Someone is already making a profile, 
                please wait")
                currentcreater = ctx.author
                dir = r'C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\DiscordMMO\User-Profiles'
                MessageAuthor = str(ctx.author)
                ProfileDIR = os.path.join(dir,MessageAuthor)
                doesExist = os.path.exists(ProfileDIR)
               if doesExist == False:
                   embed=discord.Embed(title="Creating Profile", description=f"{MessageAuthor}, your profile is being created.")
                   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

and done.